# pgadmin modify "View/Edit Data" default query

Tags: pgadmin, pgadmin-4

I want to see all the data from a table so I right-click on my table name and choose "View/Edit Data" > "All Rows"

However, it runs the following command:

```
SELECT * FROM public.my_table
ORDER BY col_A ASC, col_B ASC, col_C ASC
```

However this `ORDER BY` is not convenient at all.
How can I change the default query and make it the following by default?

```
SELECT * FROM public.my_table
ORDER BY col_B ASC, col_C ASC, col_A ASC
```

I do not want to use the query tool as the new one will be the same every time

Comment: There can be many tables with different types of columns. How do you think pgAdmin should decide the order of columns in order by clause?

Comment: I don't know how it chooses, it does somehow, I would like to change it, regardless of how it chose the first version

Comment: AFAIK, it adds the order by for all the primary keys by default. You can change it from the filter button of the toolbar.